# click handler in jquery and changing css background color

Tags: jquery

I've been experimenting with jQuery. It has a click handler that I'm wondering about.

This works:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert("Zing!");
});
```

This doesn't:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    this.css("background-color","blue");
});
```

can I change the color of the selected div with `.click()`?
Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RyPgT/

All the examples in the jQuery API are using `.on("click", function(){...});` Are there other, better ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change your code to this :

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
});
```

The problem is that `this` is a standard DOM element, without the `css` function, that's why you must make it a jQuery element using `$(this)`.

Comment: thanks, It worked. And you had a great explanation for why it works. here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyPgT/